# Thread speed in port reading

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I am trying to create a Windows Forms application with c# that reads the serial port and return values to a `DataTable`. I have created a new thread (I have tried to create a thread with both threading and `BackgroundWorker`) to read the port and then displaying the values in the `DataTable`.

My problem is that even without the port reading I can't get more than 100 values per second. Here is my code without port reading (just writing the same value to every row of the `DataTable`:

```
namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{
    public partial class BackgroundWorkerExample : Form
    {
        private int counter = 0;
        private bool threadRunning = false;
        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public BackgroundWorkerExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void BackgroundWorkerExample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear DataTable
            dt.Clear();

            //Add Collumns
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Value");
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(TimeSpan));


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            threadRunning = true;
            Thread oThread = new Thread(countUp);
            oThread.Start();


        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TimerLabel.Text = timer.ToString();
            threadRunning = false;
        }


        private void countUp()
        {
            while (threadRunning)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["Name"] = counter;
                newRow["Value"] = 5;
                newRow["Time"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

                counter++;

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Here the method `countUp` is running in a separate thread. If I don't create a new thread and run `countUp`in my main form thread the application will never return but it is much faster.

Comment: In future, please add a programming language tag such as c# to questions containing/about code. This will help people who are familiar with the programming language in question to find your question.

Answer (score 4):

This test is already drastically wrong, it cannot prove anything.  Controls like DataGridView are fundamentally thread-unsafe, you cannot update them from a worker thread.  Winforms is usually pretty good about throwing an IllegalOperationException but that only works when you access the control properties directly.  It unfortunately doesn't throw for data binding, like you use here.

This kind of bug is very hard to diagnose because it doesn't actually go wrong often enough.  You usually get a painting glitch, the control not displaying a row you added, and you think nothing of it.  Especially when you add them at a high rate.  But the mishaps are not limited to just that, triggering a deadlock is possible as well.  You certainly *do* notice that, your UI just freezes.  It just doesn't happen nearly enough, maybe once a day or a week, never when you're debugging your code.  Which also makes it next to impossible to find out *why* your program is failing.

Doing this correctly requires one of two ways:

- Unbind the grid by setting its DataSource property to null *on the UI thread*.  Then create the data table on the worker thread.  Then rebind the grid after the worker is completed by setting DataSource *on the UI thread*.
- Create one or more DataRows on the worker, add them to the DataTable *on the UI thread*.

For a serial port, you'd be likely to consider the second bullet.  You must use Control.BeginInvoke() to ensure the update occurs on the UI thread.  To make it performant, you need to ensure that you invoke to the UI thread as infrequently as possible.  The thread context switch is pretty slow, it usually hovers around half a millisecond.  But greatly depends on how busy the UI thread is.  And it is usually pretty busy trying to keep the grid updated when you throw rows at it.

One big advantage you have is that it only needs to be as fast as the human eye.  Which is not very good at seeing rapid updates, it all just turns into a blur when you do it faster than 20 times per second.  So invoking more frequently than that is just wasted cpu cycles.

So be sure to collect enough rows in your DataReceived event handler to avoid pummeling the UI thread with micro-updates.  Which are almost as expensive as a bulk update.  You can get it to fundamentally fall over, albeit unlikely for a serial port, when the rate at which you generate rows is greater than the rate at which the UI thread can add them and paint them.  You'll notice that by the UI no longer visibly painting itself anymore and not responding to the mouse and keyboard.  The only cure for that mishap is to intentionally lower the update rate in the worker.

And don't forget to *remove* rows, as written there is no throttle that prevents the data table from getting a limitless number of rows.  That's going to bomb your program with OOM.  Takes a while, it will drastically slow down first and you'd likely notice the UI going catatonic first.